# How to kick user back on homepage without using Navigations in IOS app

Tags: ios, xcuitest, testautomationfx

Background- I have an Ios Native app for which i am automating test scripts in XCUITest. The current test case flow in a class is as setup device,install app open app-> login ->perform action

for the second test case method it logs out first from the first test case action using navigations and starts

Is there any way that after end of each test case method run it directly jumps on the homepage without using navigations? Navigations takes extra time for large suite to run.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.2**

I think don't understand your question but if you want jump to homepage without navigation, you could use this line of code:

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = HomeViewController()
```

and if you don't want to jump up with little animation, use this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else { return }
            UIView.transition(with: window, duration: 0.5, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
                UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = HomeViewController()
            }, completion: { completed in
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve faster navigation for your UI tests, you can use the benefit of launching app with launch arguments.

Edit Scheme > Run > add "UITEST" to Arguments Passed On Launch

For example in your codes define

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var uiTestModeKey = "UITEST"
    static var uiTestMode = false
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        if (CommandLine.arguments.contains(uiTestModeKey)) {
           AppDelegate.uiTestMode = true
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

and in the part you want to navigate back quickly you could define something like:

```
func onActionComplete() {
    if (AppDelegate.uiTestMode) {
        navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
        //Or set the window to a new instance like
        //UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = HomeViewController()
    }
}
```